# How to save a file to downloads using WinUI 3?

Tags: windows, file-io, winui-3

How do I save a file generated by my application to the downloads folder when using the WinUI 3 SDK?  I know I can use FilePicker to select a file to use in my application but I would like to essentially do the opposite and save a file from my application somewhere or just simply put it into downloads.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example saving the StoreLogo.png file, which is in the Assets folder by default, to the Downloads folder.

```cs
using Windows.Storage;
...

// Get the StoreLogo.png file as a StorageFile.
Uri storeLogoUri = new($"ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png");
StorageFile storeLogoFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(storeLogoUri);

// Get the Downloads folder as a StorageFolder.
string downloadsFolderPath = UserDataPaths.GetDefault().Downloads;
StorageFolder downloadsFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(downloadsFolderPath);

// Save (copy) the StoreLogo.png file.
await storeLogoFile.CopyAsync(downloadsFolder);
```